# What's the definition of $\omega$?

Tags: set-theory, definition, cardinals, ordinals

This is a follow up on a comment to one of my [previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228452/why-does-omega-have-the-same-cardinality-in-every-transitive-model-of-zf). What's the definition of $\omega$?

Are the following equivalent definition of $\omega$:

1. $\omega$ is the initial ordinal of $\aleph_0$.
2. $\omega$ is the least/first infinite ordinal.
3. $\omega$ is the set of all finite ordinals.
4. $\omega$ is the first non-zero limit ordinal

If yes, are there any more equivalent definitions, not on this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to summarise what I have learnt from this question:

Point (1) is circular since $\aleph_0$ is defined to be the cardinality of $\omega$.

Let's assume that we define $\omega$ to be the first ordinal of infinite cardinality. Then it must contain all finite ordinals since the ordinals are a linear order with respect to $\subseteq$. From this it is immediately clear that (2) and (3) are equivalent. It is similarly easy to see that (4) is equivalent to (3).

Comment: Or simply to **be** $\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is it not ok to make the distinction between $\mathbb N$ and $\omega$ (as I described in the set theory chat)?

Comment: I was talking about $\aleph_0$ there: for me it simply **is** $\omega$. Frankly, I tend to use $\Bbb N$ when I want to use $\omega$ but suspect that my readers won’t be familiar with it. I suppose that if I did anything with PA, I’d use it there as well. In general I don’t think of PA at all when I think of $\omega$: it’s simply the first limit ordinal.

Comment: @Brian, Matt: There is a minor difference between $\Bbb N$ and $\omega$. Where $\Bbb N$ is *the* model of second-order PA, the one true model in the entire universe, $\omega$ is an ordinal, and if one works with models of set theory - and in particular with non-well founded models - then one has to make the distinctions between the various $\omega$'s. The notation of $\Bbb N$ is preserved for *the* unique model of second-order PA, whereas $\omega$ is just an ordinal with cool properties (measurable, supercompact, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

$\omega$ is defined to be the set of all finite ordinals.

This is provably equivalent to the assertion "the least infinite ordinal" or "the least limit ordinal" (note that $0$ is **not** a limit ordinal. It is $0$).

It can be stated as the smallest inductive set. Or the set of all ordinals whose rank is finite.

Indeed it is also defined to be $\aleph_0$.

Comment: What about point 1 on the list?

Comment: @Matt: I’m not even sure what you mean by point 1. What is your definition of $\aleph_0$ for that point?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I guess I want to define it as $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb N| = |\omega|$ so that my point 1 becomes circular.

Comment: Minus one for promoting falsehood in boldface. But of course, I would't down vote you or anyone else who is being nice and is trying to help me : )

Comment: @Matt: No... zero was *never* a limit ordinal. Soon you will tell me that the empty set has a minimal element too.

Comment: One can define limit ordinal to be any ordinal that is not a successor ordinal. Clearly, zero is not a successor ordinal.

Comment: As for the OP: I might delete this and repost it in a new thread now that my actual question has become clearer.

Comment: @Matt: One can also define limit ordinals as ordinals which stand on their hands while clapping like a unicorn. That doesn't mean this is a good definition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In my experience, most instances of being a "limit" ordinal can be elegantly replaced with the simpler condition of not being a successor ordinal. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ordinal+number) also takes the convention of defining "limit ordinal" as "any ordinal which is not a successor of any other ordinal."

Comment: @user76284: And then $0$ is a limit ordinal. Which some people take as the definition, sure, but I prefer to separate $0$ to its own special category.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a definition that works even without the axiom of infinity, in which case $\omega$ can be a proper class. Namely, $\omega$ is the class of finite ordinals. An ordinal $\alpha$ is *finite* if $\alpha=0=\emptyset$ or $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal that has only $0$ and other succesor ordinals as predecessors.

Comment: Before I up vote I will have to be sure that $\omega$ in your definition is actually a proper class. As of now I think it is a set.

Comment: @Matt: It can be. $V_\omega$ is a model of $\mathbf{ZF}-\mathbf{Inf}+\lnot\mathbf{Inf}$ in which $\omega$ is a proper class: Michael’s definition works fine, but $\omega\notin V_\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to say: $\omega$ is the order type of the natural numbers with its usual order.  All those others are theorems or common identifications.

Comment: But if you consider a non-standard model which has non-standard integers? Then this definition fails (externally).

Comment: @Asaf: I think your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: But all these definitions in the question are internal, whereas yours is external. I think it is actually quite relevant, especially in light of the other recent questions b Matt.